# How to force a CSV column to treat numbers as text, in C# using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have a C# program that is reading data from a RESTful API, and outputting it into a CSV file.

```
            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                //serialize the data into the Devices[] array RootObject
                RootObject ro = new RootObject();
                ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);

                //create a new DataTable with columns specifically required
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("tblDevices");
                dt.Columns.Add("AssetNumber");
                dt.Columns.Add("DeviceFriendlyName");
                dt.Columns.Add("IMEI");

                //iterate through each device data and add it into a DataRow
                foreach(Device d in ro.Devices)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    dr["AssetNumber"] = d.AssetNumber;
                    dr["DeviceFriendlyName"] = d.DeviceFriendlyName;

                    dr["IMEI"] = '"'+d.Imei+'"';   //<-- this is always a "number" in CSV
```

And the stringbuilder code:

```
                    //now turn the datatable into a enumerated string
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                      Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                    //read each row of the datateble, enumrate and save into the StringBuilder object
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                    }

                    //finally save the string as a CSV file
                    string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
                    string wsFileName = FilePath+"\\airwatch_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")+".csv";
                    File.WriteAllText(wsFileName, sb.ToString());
```

The IMEI number I get is always a number in Excel, when I open the CSV.

So instead of it showing me the number as a string - "353034999819999", it's showing it to me as "3.53034E+14". Yes it's a big number.

I don't want it as an Exponential. I want is as a string in Excel.

I've tried double-quotes around the field, as shown above in the code and it's always passed as a number. I've also tried the single quote at the beginning of the value, but it looks like a string with a single-quote at the start.

How can I save this value in a CSV file, as a string - not a number?

Comment: Try to put the number into quotes this way `"=""353034999819999"""`, see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/318421/617256)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On excel format that column as Number:

[image]

**If you do not want to do that then you can try this code:**

```cs
// make sure you use the CsvHelper nuget package.
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var recordsToSave = new List<Foo>();
        recordsToSave.Add(new Foo()
        {
            LargeNumber = "=\"353034999819999\"",
            Name = "SomeName"
        });

        var fileStream = new FileStream("output.csv", FileMode.CreateNew);
        using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
        csv.WriteRecords(recordsToSave);
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string LargeNumber { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Look it sort of works, but when I convert the value to text (=VALUETOTEXT([@IMEI])) within Excel, I get what I am really after, and after I do a copy/paste as values. So your answer is >>close<< but not quite right. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Hi if it helps you i have a `DataGridView` with a colmun that looks like "8940012004412026012". For export into CVS I use:

```
 if (rap_cuiclient.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv";
            sfd.FileName = "Output.csv";
            bool fileError = false;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(sfd.FileName);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        fileError = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Tabelul este gol" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (!fileError)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int columnCount = rap_cuiclient.Columns.Count;
                        string columnNames = "";
                        string[] outputCsv = new string[rap_cuiclient.Rows.Count + 1];
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                        {
                            columnNames += rap_cuiclient.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                        outputCsv[0] += columnNames;

                        for (int i = 1; (i - 1) < rap_cuiclient.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                            {
                                outputCsv[i] += rap_cuiclient.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + ",";
                            }
                        }

                        File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, outputCsv, Encoding.UTF8);
                        MessageBox.Show("Datele au fost exportate cu scucces !!!", "Info");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nu sunt date pentru export !!!", "Info");
        }
```

[image]

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is this showing you the number as a string in Excel? I assume this code - Cells[j].Value.ToString() is what converts the number to a string, but the real test is when you open the CSV in Excel - what does it look like?

Comment: try to open a new file in Excel go to Data select From Text and select the CSV file when you get to Step 3 of Text Import Wizard select Text in Column and the tabel Column with the big nomber